# How to get the current user and its token in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

My android app uses firebase to authenticate and manage users. The sign in and account creation seems to be working fine, however when I try to get the user token after the user has created an account in order to save some data to my backend, the user token is null.

Here is the **SignUpMainFragment**:

```
public class SignUpMainFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText mEmailEditText;
    private EditText mPasswordEditText;

    private SignUpListener mCallback;

    public SignUpMainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public interface SignUpListener {
        void signUp(String email, String password);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up_main, container, false);
        Button continueButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sign_up_continue_button);
        mEmailEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.sign_up_email_edit_text);
        mPasswordEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.sign_up_password_edit_text);

        continueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Validate the data and if successful continue if not get user to re-enter data.
                final String email = mEmailEditText.getText().toString();
                final String password = mPasswordEditText.getText().toString();
                if (Validate.isEmailValid(email) && Validate.isPasswordValid(password)) {
                    mCallback.signUp(email, password);
                } else if (!Validate.isEmailValid(email) && !Validate.isPasswordValid(password)) {
                    mEmailEditText.setError("Email invalid");
                    mPasswordEditText.setError("Password invalid");
                } else if (!Validate.isEmailValid(email)) {
                    mEmailEditText.setError("Email invalid");
                } else {
                    mPasswordEditText.setError("Password invalid");
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof SignUpListener) {
            mCallback = (SignUpListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallback = null;
    }
}
```

Here is the **SignUpActivity**:

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SignUpMainFragment.SignUpListener,
        SignUpAboutFragment.DoneListener, SignUpActivityView {

    public static final String SIGN_UP_MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG = "sign_up_main_fragment";
    public static final String SIGN_UP_ABOUT_FRAGMENT_TAG = "sign_up_about_fragment";

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    private SignUpActivityPresenter mPresenter;

    private String mUserId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        mPresenter = new SignUpActivityPresenter(this);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    mUserId = user.getToken(true).toString();
                    Fragment signUpAboutFragment = new SignUpAboutFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.sign_up_fragment_container, signUpAboutFragment, SIGN_UP_ABOUT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            }
        };

        Fragment signUpMainFragment = new SignUpMainFragment();

        mPresenter.addInitialFragment(signUpMainFragment, SIGN_UP_MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void signUp(String email, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        /**
                         *  If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                         *  the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                         *  signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                         */
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {  }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void saveAboutData(String firstName, String lastName, String birthday) {
        mPresenter.saveUserData(firstName, lastName, birthday, mUserId, this, MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    /**
     * Activity view operations.
     *
     * @param fragment to be initially added.
     * @param TAG the fragment tag.
     */

    @Override
    public void addInitialFragment(Fragment fragment, String TAG) {
        Fragment savedFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SIGN_UP_MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if (savedFragment == null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.sign_up_fragment_container, fragment, TAG);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivity(Context context, Class activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, activity);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This fragment validates the entered user credentials and if they are valid, it makes an interface callback to the activity actually creating the account. When the account is created the auth state listener should have been called and the current `FirebaseUser` should be non null. I then set the global member variable `mUserId` to `user.getToken(true).toString()` this is then later used to save the data in the SignUpAboutFragment fragment.

So why is the `mUserId` member variable **null** and how do I fix this to return the actual user token?

Answer (score 1):

You can use token listener to get the current user token

```
   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
        if (firebaseAuth.currentUser != null) {
            firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.getIdToken(true).addOnSuccessListener {tokenResult->
                Timber.d("CurrentUserIdToken " + tokenResult.token)
            }
        }
    }
```